# Ionic - Firebase : Get Current Time and Disable Past Dates

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, firebase

I am working on a project where you book hotel reservations.In the add booking page, I have an input datetime-local  where the user selects the date and the time of the booking.

I want to get the online time and not use the device time to disable the user from booking past datetimes.

I tried to get the server time Timestamp from Firebase but did not know how to work with it.

I want to know what is the best way to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For firebase3, use firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

```
$scope.createdDate = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

[doc is available here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#server-timestamps)

and for date time picker go for [this](http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/98/JQuery-Date-Picker-example-to-disable-previous-dates.aspx) code.